# How can I set a default selected item for my gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have a gallery and I want to set a default selected item when I launch the activity.

The goal is to have the contain of the first item appears automatically.

Is there anyway to do this ?

thx a lot for answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use method [`setSelection(position, animate)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: thanks it works. I found this solution too and I realized that my problem was somewhere else ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
gallery.setSelected(true);
gallery.setSelection(position);
```